# Merging documents using OpenXml and section breaks causes empty paragraphs

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I am stitching a couple of documents together with a requirement that each document should retain its header and footer information in the final document. Using AltChunk instead of raw OpenXml or DocumentBuilder saves a lot of effort with regards to styles, formatting, references, parts, etc.

Unfortunately, after a couple of days I can't seem to get a 100% working version due to a small and frustrating issue and I need some insight.

My code is loosly based on [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0b245732-35a7-47d6-bd91-d41c24be0556/preserving-header-and-footer-in-merged-word-document?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0b245732-35a7-47d6-bd91-d41c24be0556/preserving-header-and-footer-in-merged-word-document?forum=oxmlsdk)

I modify each sub document, prior to appending it (as an AltChunk) to a working document, by moving the last section properties into the last paragraph (in order to retain header and footer references), but Word seems to be adding a blank paragraph to each of these documents as it renders them in the final document.  I end up with:

**document 1 with correct header and footer**
*section properties/break*
blank paragraph
**document 2 with correct header and footer**
*section properties/break*
blank paragraph
**etc.**

I cant remove the blank paragraphs afterwards, as I ideally don't want to use WAS to render the document first.

It seems as if you cannot have a next-page section break without a following paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it seems that will not be away around my usage scenario. I would need to place the last section properties in the body element, but due to my way of processing with nested AltChunk, it would not work.

I have changed my approach completely and went back to a more detailed append procedure using OpenXml Power Tools and some LINQ to Xml.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Document Builder and works perfectly for me!

```
 var sources = new List<OpenXmlPowerTools.Source>();

 sources.Add(new OpenXmlPowerTools.Source(new WmlDocument(@tempReportPart1)));
 sources.Add(new OpenXmlPowerTools.Source(new WmlDocument(@tempReportPart2)));        

 var outputPath = @"C:\Users\xpto\Documents\TestFolder\myNewDocument.docx";

 DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, outputPath);
```

Comment: I tried this but there are no page breaks, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar empty paragraph issue while importing HTML files.

My solution is,

After inserting HTML AltChunk, I add a GUID place holder. After processing the file, I will open the file again, locate the GUID and check if there is a empty paragraph before it, if so remove the empty paragraph and GUID. it seems work perfectly in my solution.

Hope it helps.